# Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers in c++

Tags: c++, numbers, logic, palindrome

my program seems correct but I don't know why it has a logic problem

```
int main()
{
int r,s=0;
for(int i=10000;i<=998001;i++)
{
    while (i>0)
    {
        r=i%10;
        s=s*10+r;
        i=i/10;
    }
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You're changing i and your loop goes back to 0 every time.

Comment: A little [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should go a long way.

Comment: @Some programmer dude <g>

Comment: You must reset `s=0` for each new `i` and introduce `anewvariable = i` as suggested by kingW3

Comment: In some occasions, a piece of paper can replace a duck: consider two consecutive `i` and carefully write the results of what the program is doing

Comment: @ali, are you looking to get all numbers which are palindromes in this range?

Comment: That's not the way to treat newbie i think people should not view the question through its Title.

Comment: I'm sorry. But I didn't understand you @nafeesahmed.

Comment: ohh bro sorry i did not talk about you.

Comment: his question got -4 marking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and code don't seem to match Ali. You have told that you need the largest possible palindrome, but you are printing each and every reversed number. And your code has glitches too. I will list the mistakes and corresponding changes to be made:

1. using `i` as both the `for` loop counter variable and as well as the number you're reversing. This causes `i` to become `0` after every reversal and hence the `for` loop never ends. *The fix for this*... use another variable, say `num`, and equate it to `i` at the start of the loop. This ensures that `i` remains unchanged and `for` goes unfazed.
2. use `long int` instead of `int`. This avoids any anomalies and chances of junk numbers.
3. `s`(the sum variable) is initialized only at the start. Hence every time you calculate a new reversed number, it is adding `s` to its previous value. *The fix:* Initialize `s` to `0` at the start of `for` loop so that you get a fresh reversed for every `i` value.
4. You are not checking for any palindrome condition. You are just printing the reversed number. *The fix:*  Hence check if the the number is a palindrome, i.e, if the number ,i.e., `i` is equal to the reversed number, i.e., `s`

I have attached the code below. I am currently printing the greatest palindrome in the range in which you were checking. In case you need all the palindromes, just uncomment the commented `cout` line.

**CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int r, s = 0;
long int num, max = 0;
  for(long int i = 10000; i <= 998001; i++)
  {
    s = 0;
    num = i;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        r = num % 10;
        s = s * 10 + r;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    if(s == i) {
      //cout<<s<<endl;   //uncomment this line if you intend to display all palindromes
      if(i > max)
        max = i;
    }
  }
  cout<<max<<endl;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, this problem is one of the Euler projects and when I write the result that program show me the site said this answer is wrong  (997799)

Comment: @ali, can you help me out with this? The range you have mentioned here.. what is it based on? or is it an arbitrary range?